# Onclick pass item

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

data is an array of items. item is an array [id, name]
How can I access both id and name in the javascript pick_player function?
I am running python flask. I believe the jinja2 is used in the {} in the divs. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
<div class="search_scroll">
    {% for item in data %}
    <a tabindex="2" onclick="pick_player(( {{ item }} ))">
        {{ item[1] }}
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
function pick_player(player) {
    console.log(player[0], player[1]);
</script>
```

How should I accomplish this? I have all the information I need in data. I just can't access it in my javascript function pick_player()

Comment: Have you tried this : `onClick = {pick_player(item.id ,item.name)}`.

Comment: When doing as you suggested. I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: Is pick_player your own function or one from some library/package?

Comment: Its my own function. written inside <scripts></scripts>

Comment: @Superpinglan,do like this:
' {data.map((item,idx)=>{
 <a tabindex="2" onClick = {this.pick_player(item[idx].id ,item[idx].name)}>
 {{ item[idx] }}
</a>
   })} '

Comment: I cant get it to work. It comes out as a html innerText when I try as you described

Answer (score -1):

Since item is an array, you can use index to access the items of the array i.e. item[0] for item id and item[1] for item name.

Comment: But how to I put both item[0] and item[1] as params to the function pick_player() ?

Comment: You can use bind and pass the params.      
   onclick = 
    pick_player.bind(this,item[0],item[1])

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how to type it. I tried a few different ways, but i end up getting errors or nothing happens.

Comment: You can try using arrow functions.    
    onclick={() => pick_player(item[0],item[1])} Documentation link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions